# Shared Excel WorkBook is locked by another user

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs

I’ve been trying everything; this is the last chance I have.

I moved folders and files from an old Windows Server 2003 File Server to a new FS (Win Server 2008 R2) with DFS and ABE enabled.

Now, a specific **Shared** Excel file is driving me crazy, out of a sudden, lots of times per day, users are getting the following error while opening that file:
*Filename.xlsx is locked for editing by ‘another user’. Open ‘Read-Only’ or, click ‘Notify’ to open..*

I’ve already followed this, with no joy:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2012/05/14/the-definitive-locked-file-post.aspx

In any case, I strongly think this is not client-related, since it never gave that problem in the past with Windows Server 2003. I’ve found and followed many other solutions, nothing.

The users are all utilizing Office 2010 on Windows 7 machines, besides a few users who are still on Windows XP machines.

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Edit permissions settings for these files
If these files are accessed over the network you must modify the accessible options by granting permissions to all users

Comment: Thanks, problem is, it doesn't always happen, and since it's a restricted access folder I need some people with RO rights and some with Read Write..